# Find Certificate by hash in Store C#

Tags: c#, .net, store, x509certificate

How to get Certificate by hash in Windows Store using C#?

sha1 example:7a0b021806bffdb826205dac094030f8045d4daa

this loop works but:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
{
    Console.WriteLine( mCert.Thumbprint);
}

store.Close();
```

Is there a direct method?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var cert = store.Certificates.Find(
                                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                    thumbprint,
                                    true
                                  ).OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Find method on the collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find.aspx)

```
store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true)
```